# Get one value from LiveData

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have `LiveData` for Books in `ViewModel`'s constructor:

```
LiveData<List<Book>> books;

public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    books = bookRepository.getBooks();
}
```

When user creates new `book` from UI, I want attribute `book_order` to be filled with incremented maximum of `book_order` of other books. To better describe what I want, see following preudocode:

```
book.book_order = max(books.book_order) + 1;
```

So when there are three books with `book_order` 1, 2, 3 respectively, new book would have this attribute set to 4.

Question is, how can I do this with `LiveData` in `ViewModel`? I tried using `Transformations.map` to the new `LiveData`, but this approach is not working at all, `bookMax` seems to be `null`.

```
public void insertBook(Book book) {
    LiveData<Integer> bookMax = Transformations.map(books,  
        list -> {
          int value = 0;
          for(Book b: list) {
              if (value < b.getBookOrder()) {
                 value = b.getBookOrder();
              }
          }
        }
    );
    book.setBookOrder(bookMax + 1)
    bookRepository.update(book);
}
```

Any ideas how to set incremented maximum to the new book? It can be another approach than the one described here. `ViewModel` was created to separate app logic from UI. However it does not seem to do that in this case, because if I want to observe value, I need to be in `Activity`. Also, I did not find any alternative how to do this kind of getting one value from DB. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I might be totally wrong, but seems like you can use the id field of the `Book` Entity. For me `book_order`'s functionality can be totally replaced by the id for the model. And when working with `LiveData`, you can subscribe your Activity to the `ViewModel` which has a reference to your `LiveData` which should automatically display all the Books in your Master layout of the Master-Detail flow. Let me know if something like this could work and I shall post an answer with some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `books` are `livedata`, thus may **change** its value from time to time.
Whereis your `bookMax` is a **single value** that should be calculated at the moment of insertion.

To insert you need:

- get the current books list
- then calculate bookMax
- then actually insert.

```
val bookList: List<Book> = books.value   // current value. may be null!

val bookMax: Int = bookList.maxBy { it.order }.order   // find max order

// insert
val newBooks = arrayListOf(bookList)
newBooks.add(newBook)

books.value = newBooks  // update your livedata
```

**EDIT** Here is Java code

```
// get current value. may be null!
List<Book> bookList = books.getValue();
// so we better handle it early
if (bookList == null) {
    bookList = new ArrayList<>();
}

// calculate max order
int maxOrder = -1;
for (Book book : bookList) {
    if (maxOrder < book.order) {
        maxOrder = book.order;
    }
}

// create new book
Book newBook = new Book();
newBook.order = maxOrder + 1;

// add book to the list
bookList.add(newBook);

// do with new list whatever you want
// for example, you can update live data (if it is a MutableLiveData)
books.setValue(bookList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LiveData will not help in your scenario.

 
LiveData in DAO gets executed on a different thread and the new value is posted in observer code or in your case Transformation.map() callback. So you need to access book.id inside Transformation.map().


However, if you insert book in Transformation.map(), it would trigger an infinite loop since on every table entry update Transformation.map() would be called as LiveData> would change.

So, for your case:

1. Expose a method which exposes last book id
2. Insert a new entry.
3. Add a LiveData> to receive an update and display in UI.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking all books for finding max **book order**, you should make a method in your repository that will provide you max number of `book_order` from db.

Something like below pseudo code :

```
int maxOrder = bookRepository.getMaxBookOrder();
```

Now, all you need to do is while inserting new book, you can use that `maxOrder` variable to incremental purpose.

So, your insert method will be like :

```
public void insertBook(Book book) {
    int maxOrder = bookRepository.getMaxBookOrder();
    book.setBookOrder(maxOrder + 1)
    bookRepository.update(book);
}
```

Here, assuming that you're using ROOM for **persisting database**, this is the query that can help you get your maximum `book_order`:

```
SELECT MAX(book_order) FROM Book
```

---

If ROOM isn't your case then, you can do with another approach :

We first retrieve list using repository method and then find maximum from it like below pseudo :

```
List<Book> books = bookRepository.getBooks().getValue(); // Assuming getBooks() returns LiveData
```

Then find max from it and then increment it by one :

```
public void insertBook(Book book) {
    List<Book> books = bookRepository.getBooks().getValue();
    // calculating max order using loop
    int maxOrder = -1;
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (maxOrder < book.order) {
            maxOrder = book.order;
        }
    }
    book.setBookOrder(maxOrder + 1)
    bookRepository.update(book);
}
```

Even you can move this code of finding maximum to repository method as mentioned earlier like :

```
public int getMaxBookOrder() {
    List<Book> books = getBooks().getValue();
    // calculating max order using loop
    int maxOrder = -1;
    for (Book book : books) {
        if (maxOrder < book.order) {
            maxOrder = book.order;
        }
    }
    return maxOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with a `LiveData` you can create a custom one:

```
class BooksLiveData(list: List<Book>) : LiveData<List<Book>>() {

    val initialList: MutableList<Book> = list.toMutableList()

    fun addBook(book: Book) {
        with(initialList) {
            // Assuming your list is ordered
            add(book.copy(last().bookOrder + 1))
        }

        postValue(initialList)
    }
}
```

Then you can just create it and use:

```
val data = bookRepository.getBooks() // Make getBooks() return BooksLiveData now
data.addBook(userCreatedBook) // This'll trigger observers as well
```

You can still observe this live data, since it's posting `initialList` when a book is added, it'll notify observers. You can change it more, for example, to return the book that's added etc.

**Side note:** It might be better to extend from `MutableLiveData` instead, since `LiveData` is not supposed to update its value but internally you're posting something so it might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**
You can use an Auto Increment field or the `PrimaryKey` such as an `id` for the `book_order`'s functionality. You can even name it `book_order` if you want to. Make your Model or Entity class Like:

```
public class Book{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int book_order;
    //other data members, constructors and methods
}
```

So that, the the `book_order` gets incremented on each `Book` added to the database.

Next you can have your `ViewModel` classs like:

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
    LiveData<List<Book>> books;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        bookRepository = AppRepository.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        books = bookRepository.getBooks();
    }

}
```

Now you can subscribe your list Activity to this ViewModel (ie. make your activity observe the ViewModel) by putting the call to following method in your activity's `onCreate()`:

```
private void initViewModel() {
    final Observer<List<Book>> bookObserver= new Observer<List<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Book> books) {
            bookList.clear();
            bookList.addAll(books);

            if (mAdapter == null) {
                mAdapter = new BooksAdapter(bookList, YourActivity.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(MyViewModel.class);

    mViewModel.mBooks.observe(this, notesObserver); //mBooks is member variable in ViewModel class
}
```

Doing these things, you will be able to receive updates, ie. whenever a `Book` is added to your database by the user, the List/ Recycler view should automatically display the newly added `Book`.

**Approach 2:**
If this is not what you have wanted at all and you only want to find the latest added book's order, you can skip the third code block completely and use the following in your `Dao`:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books")
int getCount();
```

which gives the total number of books ie. rows in the books table, which you can then call from your repository, which in turn can be called from your ViewModel which in turn can be called from the Activity.

**Approach 3:**
If you want the `book_order` which I think is the latest number of books in the database after a new book is added, you can use Approach 1 which gives you the List of Book in the ViewModel. You can then get the number of books from the booklist count.

**Important!**
either way you would want to edit your `insertBook()` method in your editor or newBook ViewModel and make it something like:

```
public void insertBook(Book book) {
    Book book= mLiveBook.getValue(); //declare mLiveBook as MutableLiveData<Book> in this ViewModel

//maybe put some validation here or some other logic

    mRepository.insertBook(book);
}
```

and in your Repository corresponding insert would look like:

```
public void insertBook(final Book book) {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDb.bookDao().insertBook(book);
        }
    });
}
```

and corresponding Dao method:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertBook(Book book);
```